# Postgresql 9.2.15 on Centos 7.2 failed to bind to ipv4

Tags: postgresql, centos7

Ran the following for a fresh install.

```
yum install postgresql-server postgresql-contrib
postgresql-setup initdb
systemctl start postgresql
```

With standard config, no changes or anything.

```
Nov 02 10:33:17 xxx.org pg_ctl[87482]: LOG:  could not bind IPv4 socket: Address already in use
Nov 02 10:33:17 xxx.org pg_ctl[87482]: HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
```

But it actually has binded to 127.0.0.1:5432 fine. I ran netstat -anp before postgres started and 5432 port isn't in use. After I started postgresl I can see it has binded to 5432 successfully.

```
netstat -anp | grep 5432
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12421/postgres      
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     46516    12421/postgres       /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     46514    12421/postgres       /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

I installed it on another identical server last week with the same image and it is perfectly fine. I compared the pg version and the /etc/hosts file and they are the same.  I even copied the same postgres conf over and it still gave me the same problem. Postgresql is started and I can connect fine! just annoying that it  is throwing up that message when it starts.

Answer (score 0):

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
```

Turns out that you need this in postgresql.conf. Even though by default, it binds to that port!